# CSS-only animation interferes with Bootstrap4's Navbar Toggler on mobile devices

Tags: css, animation, bootstrap-4

I am building a background animation with CSS only. I want some images/colors moving in the same order from left to right in an infinite loop.

It works like I want with the code below. But I have problems on mobile devices (tested Chrome 85.0.4183.127 on Android and iPhone 6/7/8 iOS 11 on Firefox Dev Tools), where the animation is moving the Bootstrap's Navbar Toggler.

Sorry for the long code, I could'nt reproduce it with less.

Any Ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //stop animation
  $(".play_animation").click(() => {
    if ($(".backgroundAll").css("animation-play-state") == "paused") {
      $(".backgroundAll").css("animation-play-state", "running");
      $(".play_animation.fa-pause").css("display", "block");
      $(".play_animation.fa-play").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(".backgroundAll").css("animation-play-state", "paused");
      $(".play_animation.fa-pause").css("display", "none");
      $(".play_animation.fa-play").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.play_animation.fa-play {
  display: none;
}

.backgroundAll {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  opacity: 0.3; /* not fucking 30% due to fucking Safari (e.g. version 10.1.2) */
}

#background1 {
  left: -100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: bg_first 10s linear;
}

@keyframes bg_first {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 100vw;
  }
}

#background2 {
  left: -100vw;
  background-color: red;
  animation: bg_regular 20s linear infinite;
}

#background3 {
  left: -100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: bg_regular 20s linear 10s infinite;
}

/* add multiple backgrounds */

@keyframes bg_regular {
  from {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 100vw;
  }
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mtCustom {
  margin-top: 63px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
    <div id="nav" class="row bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark h5">
          <a class="navbar-brand my-n3 pt-3" href="">
                        Logo
                    </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="">Link2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="">Link1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="background1" class="backgroundAll"></div>
    <div id="background2" class="backgroundAll"></div>
    <div id="background3" class="backgroundAll"></div>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="row mtCustom">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="text-center">
            <span class="float-right">
                            <i class="play_animation fas fa-pause"></i>
                            <i class="play_animation fas fa-play"></i>
                        </span>
            <h1 class="py-5">Header</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what is moving exactly? do you mean Logo and the 2 link items are not aligned vertically?

Comment: If you run this code on mobile the navbar toggler will move to the right out of the screen. Furthermore the screen somehow expands on the bottom. I could'nt figure out the reason, but I found a solution with "position: fixed" for the background, which I can post later.

Comment: ok let me check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.backgroundAll {
  position: fixed;
  [...]
```

did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to position the toggler absolutely at the Bootstrap media queries built-in breakpoints (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/)

Add this to CSS code

```
.navbar {
position:relative
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
.navbar-toggler-icon {
position:absolute!important;
left:75px;top:2.5px;
}}
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/QWEjeEY

Questions? Just comment below.